# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when creating observable collection from list

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, observablecollection, unit-of-work

In my application, I am creating observable collection from list.
List is collection of my database Table.
List display correct result but when i create observable collection it gives me Exception as
`Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.
And this happend some times when i run my application with large Database.For small database it works fine.

**Code:**

```
var list = db.Contacts.ToList();
ObservableCollection collection = new ObservableCollection(list);
```

Exception:

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

**Stack Trace**

```
 at System.Data.Linq.IdentityManager.StandardIdentityManager.InsertLookup(MetaType type, Object instance)
   at System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.InsertLookupCachedObject(MetaType type, Object instance)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReaderBase`1.InsertLookup(Int32 iMetaType, Object instance)
   at Read_Contact(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.CopyFrom(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
```

**Target Site**

```
{System.Object InsertLookup(System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MetaType, System.Object)}
```

What i am doing wrong?
Thanx in advance

---

**Edit:**

Above is only a small part of my code. In my actual code, I use UnitOfWork and Repository Pattern. To debug the problem I tried to print all the ID's of entities via `foreach` loop.

```
  foreach (var item in _uow.Contacts.Query(q => !q.ContactID.Equals(1)))
  {
     i = item.ContactID;
  }
```

But suddenly after some 25534 (random figures everytime I get), `_uow.Contacts.Query(q => !q.ContactID.Equals(1)` is not able to get the next element. In other words Enumerator.MoveNext() isn't performed. Of course this may be if next element is `null`, but it isn't. I have added a Watch to list to confirm it.

Comment: i am thinking it will be due to no data in list so just put a check before making observableCollection on list ie it is empty or not..just a guess.

Comment: List fill with correct data with all values in database.

Comment: if you getting problem in this so you can do a workaround that is make this lst a property with get set; and implement Inotifypropertychanged on this lst and now you bind this lst to anythind control. i am telling you this because i don't know whether you can convert list to observablecollection directlty.

Comment: As you have said i tried to check my list is proper or not and actauly list is throwing Exception.

Comment: Tolist() is your method or is badly written ? I think it should be ToList().

Answer (score 0):

In this code, either `db` or `Tables` is `null`.

```
var list = db.Tables.ToList();
```

Make sure to check that before:

```
if (db != null && ds.Tables != null)
{
var list = db.Tables.ToList();
}
```